# How prove this inequality $\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^4}{a^2+2b^4}\ge 1$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, fractions, symmetric-polynomials, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Let $a,b,c>0$ such $a+b+c=3$. Show that
>   $$\dfrac{a^4}{a^2+2b^4}+\dfrac{b^4}{b^2+2c^4}+\dfrac{c^4}{c^2+2a^4}\ge 1$$

My  attempt is to use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Hence, I consider 
$$\left(\dfrac{a^4}{a^2+2b^4}+\dfrac{b^4}{b^2+2c^4}+\dfrac{c^4}{c^2+2a^4}\right)(a^2+b^2+c^2+2a^4+2b^4+2c^4)\ge (a^2+b^2+c^2)^2$$However,
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2\le (a^2+b^2+c^2+2a^4+2b^4+2c^4)$$

Answer (score 3):

By  C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^4}{a^2+2b^4}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^8}{a^6+2a^4b^4}\geq\frac{(a^4+b^4+c^4)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^6+2a^4b^4)}.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$(a^4+b^4+c^4)^2\geq\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^6+2a^4b^4)$$ or
$$a^8+b^8+c^8\geq a^6+b^6+c^6$$ or
$$9(a^8+b^8+c^8)\geq(a+b+c)^2(a^6+b^6+c^6),$$
which is obvious by Power Mean inequality:
$$\left(\frac{a^8+b^8+c^8}{3}\right)^{\frac{2}{8}}\geq\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^2$$ and
$$\frac{a^6+b^6+c^6}{3}\leq\left(\frac{a^8+b^8+c^8}{3}\right)^{\frac{6}{8}}.$$
Done!

The inequality $a^8+b^8+c^8\geq a^6+b^6+c^6$ we can prove also by the following way.

We need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^8-a^6)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^6(a-1)(a+1)-2(a-1))\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a-1)(a^7-1+a^6-1)\geq0,$$
which is obvious.